# How can I "generate" template spezialations for a function from a variadic template argument?

Tags: c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I think I will first show the example and then explain it:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T_, size_t size_>
struct arg
{
    using T = T_;
    static constexpr size_t size = size_;
};

template<typename... Arugments>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename Argument>
    std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size>& getArray() // specializations of all args in Arguments should be generated
    {
        static std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size> arr;
        return arr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<arg<int, 10>, arg<float, 10>, arg<float, 1>> myFoo;
    myFoo.getArray<arg<int, 10>>();
    myFoo.getArray<arg<float, 10>>(); // should return a different array than the line above
    myFoo.getArray<arg<bool, 1>>(); // should NOT work because arg<bool, 10> is was not passed to Foo
}
```

If got a struct `arg` which contains the information how to construct `arr` in `getArray`. A list of args is passed to `Foo`. Now I want that template specializations of `getArray` to be generated for each `arg` in `Arguments`. If no specialization was generated for a specific `arg` I want that some kind of error occurs.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `static_assert` to make sure `Argument` is part of `Arguments` with a helper struct.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... T>
struct contains;

template <typename T>
struct contains<T> : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Rest>
struct contains<T, U, Rest...> : contains<T, Rest...>  {};

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
struct contains<T, T, Rest...> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T_, std::size_t size_>
struct arg
{
    using T = T_;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = size_;
};

template<typename... Arguments>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename Argument>
    std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size>& getArray() // specializations of all args in Arguments should be generated
    {
        static_assert(contains<Argument, Arguments...>(), "Invalid type");
        static std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size> arr;
        return arr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<arg<int, 10>, arg<float, 10>, arg<float, 1>> myFoo;
    myFoo.getArray<arg<int, 10>>()[5] = 7;
    myFoo.getArray<arg<float, 10>>(); // should return a different array than the line above
    //myFoo.getArray<arg<bool, 1>>(); // should NOT work because arg<bool, 10> is was not passed to Foo

    Foo<arg<int, 10>, arg<float, 10>, arg<float, 1>> myFoo2;
    std::cout << myFoo2.getArray<arg<int, 10>>()[5];

    Foo<arg<int, 10>, arg<float, 10>, arg<double, 1>> myFoo3;
    std::cout << myFoo3.getArray<arg<int, 10>>()[5];
}
```

Just wanted to also point out that as demonstrated by the code, `myFoo` and `myFoo2` returns the same array since they are the exact same type.

`myFoo3` on the other hand is a separate type, which means the `getArray` member function is a separate function and has it's own copy of the same type array.

Comment: Too much code. A one-line fix works: `static_assert(((std::is_same_v<Argument, Arguments>) || ...), "Invalid type");`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. This is C++11 not C++17. Fold expressions were only introduced in C++17.

Comment: Well you answered to my question and I made a mistake in my code, because as you pointed out @super `myFoo2` will have the same array as `myFoo`. But is there a workaround for that, such that `arr` acts like a non-static member? I would actually have preferred to do a non-static member template but this is not possible.

Comment: I will actually open a new Question for this.

Comment: @2b-t yeah missed that tag.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Already happened a couple of times to me too. :)

Comment: this is the new question i've opend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466726/replacement-for-non-static-non-const-variable-templates