# Replacement for non-static non-const variable templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variables

I've just opened a question [about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465549/how-can-i-generate-template-spezialations-for-a-function-from-a-variadic-templ) but unfortunately, as @super pointed out in his answer, defining `arr` static in the function `getArray` is not what I want. I would like something like a non-static non-const variable template but that specifically is not supported in c++ up until now. Is there some workaround for this which has the same effect as a non-static non-const variable template.

EDIT

This would be how I would expect the syntax to be if it was supported:

```
#include <array>


template<typename T_, size_t size_>
struct arg
{
    using T = T_;
    static constexpr size_t size = size_;
};

template<typename... Arugments>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename Argument>
    std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size> arr;
    
    template<typename Argument>
    std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size>& getArray() // specializations of all args in Arguments should be generated
    {
        return arr<Argument>;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<arg<int, 10>> myFoo;
    myFoo.getArray<arg<int, 10>>()[0] = 1;
    Foo<arg<int, 10>> myFoo2;
    myFoo2.getArray<arg<int, 10>>()[0] = 2; // should not affect the arr of myFoo
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for returning a reference? What are you planning to do with the return type?

Comment: Can you show what you want the code to look like? (even if it doesn't actually compile because non-static non-const variable templates aren't supported)

Comment: @2b-t I have to admit the example is kind of bad, I probably over simplified the problem, but I have a class which needs a list of static size and instead of `arg` I use typenames to kind of create a map that is evaluated at compile time, because many of the members of this "map" have different types. To answer your question no there is no particular reason that it needs to return a reference.

Comment: @GianLaager What should happen if there is a duplicate inside `Arguments`, meaning two time the exact same template? Can it happen or rather not?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
struct Foo
{
    template<typename Argument>
    std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size> arr;
};
```

is not possible because you are asking the compiler to create a structure with an unknown number of variables in it (one for every type that's used as a template parameter). It works when the variable is static because then the variables don't have to be next to each other in memory and the compiler can just create them when they are requested. When they're non-static, the compiler has to work out the memory layout of `struct Foo` and it can't do that since it can't see the future, or other source files.

However, you want to have one variable for each type in the parameter pack `Arguments`. And you *can* do that... with some weird trickery. You can have one base class per type, and you can have one variable per base class. This is how classes like `std::tuple` and `std::variant` are probably implemented with your compiler:

```
template<typename Argument>
struct FooBase
{
    std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size> arr;
};

template<typename... Arguments>
struct Foo : FooBase<Arguments>...
{
    template<typename Argument>
    std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size>& getArray()
    {
        return FooBase<Argument>::arr; // will be an error if Argument isn't in Arguments
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to to do a pack expansion on `Arguments...` somewhere. In C++14

```
template <typename... Arugments>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename Argument>
    using array_t = std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size>;

    using arrays_t = std::tuple<array_t<Arguments>...>;

    arrays_t arrs;

    // C++14 only
    template <typename Argument>
    array_t<Argument> & getArray() { 
        static_assert(contains<Argument, Arguments...>(), "Invalid type");
        return get<array_t<Argument>>(arrs); 
    }
    // and / or (also C++11)
    template <size_t I>
    std::tuple_element_t<I, arrays_t> & getArray() { 
        static_assert(I < sizeof...(Arguments), "Invalid index");
        return get<I>(arrs); 
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PpOuNJIHg94pfOBN)

Comment: This is a C++11 question and your answer is good but requires C++14 (`std::get` by typename).

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you could add some sort of non-static class member like an `std::tuple` of `std::array`s. [Caleth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467206/9938686) is a good answer but requires C++14: [**`std::get` by `typename` was only introduced in C++14**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get).

In C++11 you will have to have to use **`std::get` by index** in combination with **finding the corresponding tuple index**. You will have to define the [following helper templates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200629-00/?p=103910):

```
template<typename T, typename Tuple>
struct tuple_element_index_helper;

template<typename T>
struct tuple_element_index_helper<T, std::tuple<>> {
   static constexpr std::size_t value = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename... Rest>
struct tuple_element_index_helper<T, std::tuple<T, Rest...>> {
  static constexpr std::size_t value = 0;
  using RestTuple = std::tuple<Rest...>;
  static_assert(tuple_element_index_helper<T, RestTuple>::value == std::tuple_size<RestTuple>::value, "type appears more than once in tuple");
};

template<typename T, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct tuple_element_index_helper<T, std::tuple<First, Rest...>> {
  using RestTuple = std::tuple<Rest...>;
  static constexpr std::size_t value = 1 + tuple_element_index_helper<T, RestTuple>::value;
};

template<typename T, typename Tuple>
struct tuple_element_index {
  static constexpr std::size_t value = tuple_element_index_helper<T, Tuple>::value;
  static_assert(value < std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value, "type does not appear in tuple");
};
```

Then you can use them as follows

```
template<typename... Arguments>
struct Foo {
  private:
    using TupleType = decltype(std::make_tuple(std::array<typename Arguments::T, Arguments::size>() ...));

   public:
    TupleType arr;

    template<typename Argument>
    std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size>& getArray() {
      // equivalent to C++14 get by typename: std::get<std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size>>(arr);
      return std::get<tuple_element_index<std::array<typename Argument::T, Argument::size>, TupleType>::value>(arr);
    }
};
```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/djbJxHn02ofGbOyB)

---

What is supposed to happen if there are multiple template arguments of the same type? You could add a `static_assert` to it that guarantees that no two template parameters of the same type are allowed.